# Automatic repair for Windows 8.1 run on a dell system XPS could not repair the installation

Tags: windows, windows-8.1-upgrade

I am getting the error message:

> Invalid signature detected.

After trying to restore it, it still did not work and I don't want to format my system because of my files.

I ran restore, it did not work, rather it produced a log file: `C:\WINDOWS\System32\Logfiles\Srt\SrtTrail.txt`

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I tried the Automatic Repair on several windows 7 machines and it never worked. It's merely a waste of time. My suggestion would be:
1. If you don't care about space, just reinstall windows 8.1 without formatting your disk. 
2. If you are sensitive about free space on your harddrive. You should have a bootable disk(like a bootable flash drive with linux or something like that), try to boot it up and copy your important files out of the harddisk then reinstall windows.
3.If you have lots of time, take your harddrive to another machine and analyze the log file to see what's wrong. Then try to fix the problem and rerun the repair.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen twice on two windows 8 computers, so I'm not sure if the problem is fixed, but it might be a bootup or login file that is corrupted. it could possibly make the startup screen work, as it is a .txt file